OSX Sequoia crashes/panics intermittently on speaker usage
My MacBook Pro (13" 2020) started to crash intermittently on left speaker usage after installing macOS Sequoia. The panic log typically shows this error:
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff01b33c318): "i2c0::_checkBusStatus Bus is still in a bad state; last write status 00010110 int shadow 00010100 xfer 00000000 fifo 00000000 for device audio-tas5770L-spkr-woofer-l" @AppleS5L8940XI2C.cpp:503

The panic references both the audio-tas5770L-spkr-woofer-l and audio-tas5770L-spkr-tweeter-l components.
The issue is inconsistent—it doesn't crash every time I use the left speaker, and the behavior isn't fully reproducible. For instance, it sometimes crashes when playing music on Spotify or watching YouTube, but only occasionally, and often when there’s a system sound (e.g., deleting a file or changing the volume). Sometimes, it crashes at the start of a video or music playback, but adjusting the volume alone may work fine.
Steps I Tried (Did Not Resolve the Issue)

Updated to the latest macOS Sequoia version (15.1)
Ran Apple Diagnostics (no issues found)
Performed a standard reset (Transfer or Reset > Erase All Content and Settings)


What Finally Worked
A complete factory reset of the MacBook seems to have resolved the issue for now.
Workaround (If You Prefer Not to Factory Reset)
If you experience the same problem, here’s a workaround:

Go to System Settings > Sound and set the balance slider all the way to the right speaker.
Enable Mono Audio under System Settings > Accessibility > Audio.

This should prevent crashes related to left speaker usage by routing all audio output to the right speaker.
